# Редирект на другой сайт и потом сразу же на свой по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery-ui

Как сделать так чтобы при нажатие на кнопку пользователя перемещало на другой сайт и сразу же на мой сайт? Я думаю это делается с помощью `js`.

Comment: Это делается с помощью iframe, открытым на всю страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь переместиться на другой сайт используя js:

```
window.location.href="page.html";
```

Но ты не можешь с другого сайта вернуться обратно, если у тебя к нему нет доступа.

Если у тебя есть доступ на другой сайт, то ты можешь с первого сайта положить что-либо в localStorage (например, текущий адрес).
После перехода на второй сайт ты проверяешь localStorage и если там что-либо есть, возвращаешься обратно через тот же window.location.href.

Answer (score 0):

Делается при помощи атрибута `target` со значением `_blank`

Пример:
`<a href="url" target="_blank">link</a>`